# Writing a text file in local host using python

Tags: python, xampp, urllib

I have created a localhost server using xampp. My objective is to write a value to a text file in that server. I have already used python to read the value from the file in localhost using urllib.urlopen() function. Please help me to write values to a file

Comment: Please show what you already tried (code examples etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows

```
f = open('file_name.txt','w')
f.write('Your message here\n') 
f.close()
```

Comment: This will write to a local file.... but i need to open a file in a location "169.254.123.xxx/file_name.txt" ie. in a local server

Comment: change file path as follows `f = open('/opt/lampp/htdocs/file_name.txt','w')`

Comment: It only searches for the file int the local computer not on the server

Comment: You can write in server also